# AES encryption and decryption are not working in hexadecimal value

Tags: encryption, type-conversion, aes, twos-complement, caesar-cipher

I was working on an IoT device which I need to communicate with the device using Bluetooth. I have paired the device and I am trying to send Hexa value to the hardware and I have used AES encryption and decryption. I have mentioned the code which I used to encryption
1. The AES-128 is fixed as: **3A 60 43 2A 5C 01 21 1F 29 1E 0F 4E 0C 13 28 25**
2. Ciphertext: **06 01 01 01 2D 1A 68 3D 48 27 1A 18 31 6E 47 1A**

```
private static byte[] encrypt(byte[] sSrc, byte[] sKey) throws Exception {
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(sKey, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/NoPadding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(sSrc);
    return encrypted;
}
```

Expected output is: **ec    72  21  4c  b0  9c  d1  1b  52  fe  73  e9  01  d8  dc  48**
but i am getting Decimals from signed twos's complemnet of the output like: **-20, 114, 33, 76, -80, -100, -47, 27, 82, -2, 115, -23, 1, -40, -36, 72**

and same like in the decryption 
1. The AES-128 is fixed as: **3A 60 43 2A 5C 01 21 1F 29 1E 0F 4E 0C 13 28 25**
2. Encrypted value: **A5 6C 7D 75 48 DE FF EF E7 AC 1E A9 BC CE 66 E6**
Code used for decryption

```
private static byte[] decrypt(byte[] sSrc, byte[] sKey) throws Exception {
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(sKey, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/NoPadding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
    byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(sSrc);
    return decrypted;
}
```

expected output is: **06 02 07 5B B 71 E7 01 01 00 05 0B 86 20 18 0A**
but i am getting Decimals from signed twos's complemnet of the output like: **6, 2, 7, 91, -70, 113, -25, 1, 1, 3, 5, 11, -122, 32, 24, 10**
Please help me to sort out this issue, i have to get the out put as a hexadecimal value not in decimal form signed two's complement.

Comment: Maybe this will help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655181/how-to-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hex-string-in-java
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140131/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-hex-dump-to-a-byte-array-using-java

Comment: @MaartenBodewes thanks for your good words and helping, now I got stuck in communicating with the IoT device using BlueTooth connectivity. can you help me to sort out this issue?

Comment: Not unless I can do it from bed. But you can always ask here if you've got a specific question. I'm not a BT expert... yet.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59099008/11480411 This is my question can you help me