# Trying to connect with IoT device by bluetooth connectivity(Gatt)

Tags: android, bluetooth, iot, gatt

I am trying to communicate with an IoT device by BlueTooth connectivity. first,

1. I have paired the device using BlueTooth.
2. Then prepared the Hexadecimal value using AES encryption
3. Send a request to the device using characteristic write
4. I tried to read the response from the device using characteristic Read but I got the status as 1 and data is null.

These are the steps which I have done and the code I mentioned below.

```
BluetoothGatt gatt;
BluetoothGattCallback gattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
        super.onConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState);

        System.out.println("Lock Conn St ---"+status);
        System.out.println("Lock Conn new st  ---"+newState);
        if (newState == 2){
            gatt.discoverServices();
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
        super.onServicesDiscovered(gatt, status);

        System.out.println("Lock Conn new serv discov  ---"+status);

         if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS){



             System.out.println("gatt Success  ---");
             String getTockenString;
             /*List<BluetoothGattService> ls= gatt.getServices ();

             System.out.println("gatt List   ---"+ls.toString());*/
             //orginal key
             final byte AESkey[] = new byte[] {0x20,0x57,0x4f,0x55,0x36,0x4b,0x3f,0x47,0x39,0x50,0x41,0x58,0x91,0x63,0x2d,0x8b};
             final byte Src[] = new byte[] {0x06,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x2D,0x1A,0x68,0x3D,0x48,0x27,0x1A,0x18,0x31,0x6E,0x47,0x1A};

             try {
                 getTockenString = bytesToHex(encrypt(Src, AESkey));
                 BluetoothGattService service = gatt.getService(LOCK_SERVICE_UUID);
                 BluetoothGattCharacteristic readCharect =  service.getCharacteristic(LOCK_READ_DATA_UUID);
                 BluetoothGattCharacteristic writeCharect =  service.getCharacteristic(LOCK_WRITE_DATA_UUID);

                 gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(readCharect,true);


                 writeCharect.setValue(getTockenString.getBytes());
                 gatt.writeCharacteristic(writeCharect);

                 System.out.println("gatt AES ENC   ---"+getTockenString);

             } catch (Exception e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();

             }

         }
        System.out.println("gatt end of on descovng   ---");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
        super.onCharacteristicChanged(gatt, characteristic);

        System.out.println("gatt char   changed    ---"+ Arrays.toString(characteristic.getValue()));



    }



    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
        super.onCharacteristicWrite(gatt, characteristic, status);

        System.out.println("gatt =============== == onCharacteristicWrite  happend  ---"+status+ Arrays.toString(characteristic.getValue() ));

        BluetoothGattService service = gatt.getService(LOCK_SERVICE_UUID);
        BluetoothGattCharacteristic readCharect =  service.getCharacteristic(LOCK_READ_DATA_UUID);
        gatt.readCharacteristic(readCharect);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
        super.onCharacteristicRead(gatt, characteristic, status);

        System.out.println("gatt ================    onCharacteristicRead   happend  ---"+status );

        System.out.println("gattonCharacteristicRead value---"+ Arrays.toString(characteristic.getValue()));


    }


};
```

In the document, they have explained all the communication will be in 16 bit but when I send a request I got one 32 bit value but I don't think that is the value I am expecting. can anyone help me to solve the issue? I have to communicate with my device using BlueTooth.

Comment: which device are you trying to use? did you check the bluetooth spec for the specific IoT device(for ex temperature sensor etc.,). The reason is to be able to decipher the data from the IoT device

Comment: You have many different steps run together here with no real way of knowing which is being done incorrectly.  Start with something simpler not requiring the additional encryption.  Use a debug type app to manually interact with the device.  Or use the BT HCI snoop feature to watch some other app interact with the device.

Comment: @ManivannanRadhakannan  I am using BL10 GPS Bike Lock. I followed their documents. now I am getting 20 bits of data when reading the response from Bluetooth. but the response should be in 16 bit.  I got confirmation from the hardware team that aes is encryption is correct so i doubt is there any problem with writing and reading data

Comment: @Chris Stratton As per their document we need AES encryption to communicate with the device and as I explained in the above comment this is the problem I am facing now.

Comment: Good luck with that.

Comment: @JijoAbraham, thanks for confirming the IoT device used. do you have any reference app from the vendor, to validate their claims that it works correctly? If yes, try to validate the request you are sending with that of reference data, else follow up with the hardware team.  Also did you try validating the type of data you are receiving ? for example resp code -- payload len -- data--crc--